# Second Ordered set is not ordered

Tags: excel-2010, mdx, olap

In an `Excel OLAP Pivot` I have the following custom set called "EventsOrdered":

```
ORDER(
    {[DimensionEvents].[Events].[Event].members},
    SUM (
            TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].members, 12),
            [Measures].[Revenue]
            ),
    BDESC
)
```

When I add it as the second column to the pivot I get the following:

[image]

What it is ordering the events by is *World* revenue but I want the order of the events to be partitioned by the country e.g the yellow row should be higher up the order for the US.

Is this possible? - how do I change the MDX script to reflect this context aware behavior in Excel- I've unsuccessfully played around with some tuples that use the CURRENTMEMBER function like the following but no joy:

```
ORDER(
        {[DimensionEvents].[Events].[Event].members},
    SUM (
           (
             [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER,
             [Geolocation].[Geography].CURRENTMEMBER
           ),
           [Measures].[Revenue]
           ),
    BDESC
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try the following?:

```
ORDER(
    {[DimensionEvents].[Events].[Event].members},
    SUM (
            TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].members, 12),
            [Measures].[Revenue],
            [Geolocation].[Geography].CURRENTMEMBER
            ),
    BDESC
)
```

philip,

Comment: `SUM` is a two argument function - I think you need to maybe make a tuple from `([Date].[..,[Geoloaction].[)`

Comment: Have you tested?! Sum _cannot_ have 3 arguments.

Answer (score -1):

no you don't need to;
it's the correct answer !

Philip,